# Can't connect to SQL Database due to Error 40

Tags: c#, mysql

**Code:**

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=xxxxx;Database=x;User Id=xxx;Password=xx;");
            try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();
                String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Note: X's are on purpose

**Error:**
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while stablishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configuered to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**What I'd like to reach:**

- Connect to SQL Database and compare password and username with the
  text boxes and login if they are equals
- Prevent SQL Injection

**What I've tried:**

- New Database and Table
- Local Database
- Different Connection types

Nothing worked.

Comment: You'v tagged MySQL but the classes you're using are for SQL Server (MSSQL). Which one are you actually trying to use?

Comment: @Llama Hi, I am using a MySQL Database.

Comment: In that case you need to use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, etc. rather than `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, etc.

Comment: Solving this problem is very easy:
    1.Go to control panel.
   2. search for services.
   3. Open Local services window from your search results
    4.Restart your MSSQLSERVER service.

Comment: @Chameera Restarting a database server OP doesn't have will solve the problem of them using MSSQL classes in C# to access a MySQL database?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/resolve-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: @Chameera But how does OP restart a database server they don't have?

Comment: @Llama Thank you :) , is this SQL Injection safe though? I heard that there are different ways to prevent this.

Comment: Assuming your code updated to MySqlCommand uses parameters like this, then yeah - it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

use **mysql ado**

*If this does not work, you will probably need to enable the Authentication and logon issue to allow this user to access this database in mysql.*

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxxx;Database=x;User Id=xxx;Password=xx;");
    try
    {
          if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
             sqlCon.Open();
          String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
          MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
          sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
          sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
          sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
          int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
         if (count == 1)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Success!");
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
        sqlCon.Close();
     }
}
```